# Cordova/Phonegap change splash image dynamically

Tags: android, iphone, cordova, splash-screen

Is there a way to display different splash images depending of the locale (en/es/fr/etc) the user set in their phone? Or in general, change the splash image dynamically. I've already changed the default splash image, but my next step is to change it dynamically.

Comment: Hi @Gabriel,
Did you find any solution for the above requirement because I also have some thing similar requirement.

Comment: @ShashankHS, unfortunately no.